# Cannot get lossless compression to work with ffmpeg with upscaling on windows 10

Tags: video, ffmpeg, vlc-media-player, video-encoding

I am trying to convert a sequence of png images to a lossless video while upscaling (keeping the same aspect ratio). I have attached one png image

[image: png image].

However, every lossless option I use either is obviously not lossless, or results in corrupted video.

I have tried `ffmpeg -framerate 60 -i %d.png -vf scale=-1:2160 -c:v libx264 -crf 0 -preset veryslow -c:a libmp3lame -b:a 320k output.mp4` I tried to add the cmd line output but this website complains my question is spam if I do and won't let me post it.

Which I think should be lossless due to the -crf 0, however doing this produces a corrupted video according to vlc, windows media player and firefox. However, chrome does manage to play it, but the results in this case are obviously lossy. Shown here, you can see very clearly thick concentric bands of colour that are not there in the actual .png, which instead falls off smoothly. [Lossy Compression](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XsHiJ.png)

I have tested this with both the full set of images that I want to make into a video, and just 3 frames so that I can be sure that there is nothing wrong with the input .png, in both cases the same results occur.

I have found after searching online that adding -pix_fmt yuv420p can help, so have tried this

`ffmpeg -framerate 60 -i %d.png -vf scale=-1:2160 -c:v libx264 -crf 0 -preset veryslow -c:a libmp3lame -b:a 320k -pix_fmt yuv420p output.mp4`

Doing so allows VLC to now open it (however firefox and windows media player still say it is corrupted). However, it is still obviously lossy compressed in both chrome and VLC.

I have then tried `ffmpeg -framerate 60 -i %d.png -vf scale=-1:2160 -c:v libvpx-vp9 -lossless 1 output.webm`

Which I gather should be lossless due to -lossless 1 , however doing this results in a very weird output. In VLC and firefox, the output is just black. However in chrome, the output is mainly a green background that goes from dark green at the bottom of the screen to light green at the top, with a darker green circle in the middle, and the text in the top left has became pink. In windows media player, the output is similar however there is no dark green circle in the center, and the text in the top left has changed to a very bright light green and also been duplicated below itself in a lower resolution but bigger font and changed to a dark pink with a black outline.I don't understand how this could possibly happen

[image: very weird windows media player output]

I have then tried adding -pix_fmt yuv420p to this as before, `ffmpeg -framerate 60 -i %d.png -vf scale=-1:2160 -c:v libvpx-vp9 -lossless 1 -pix_fmt yuv420p  output.webm`

When doing this, the output in VLC and firefox is still blank, however chrome and windows media player now show normal outputs, however the result is again obviously lossy compression.

I have then attempted ffmpeg -framerate 60 -i %d.png -vf scale=-1:2160 -c:v ffv1 -c:a libmp3lame -b:a 320k output.avi

However the output is just a blank black screen in VLC, freshly installed both on a windows 10 machine and ubuntu machine. The cmd output for this is

`ffmpeg -framerate 60 -i %d.png -vf scale=-1:2160 -c:v ffv1 -c:a libmp3lame -b:a 320k output.avi
ffmpeg version N-91999-g148a21611d Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 8.2.1 (GCC) 20180813
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-amf --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth
  libavutil      56. 19.101 / 56. 19.101
  libavcodec     58. 30.100 / 58. 30.100
  libavformat    58. 18.102 / 58. 18.102
  libavdevice    58.  4.103 / 58.  4.103
  libavfilter     7. 32.100 /  7. 32.100
  libswscale      5.  2.100 /  5.  2.100
  libswresample   3.  2.100 /  3.  2.100
  libpostproc    55.  2.100 / 55.  2.100
Input #0, image2, from '%d.png':
  Duration: 00:00:10.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: png, rgb24(pc), 3840x1408, 60 fps, 60 tbr, 60 tbn, 60 tbc
Codec AVOption b (set bitrate (in bits/s)) specified for output file #0 (output.avi) has not been used for any stream. The most likely reason is either wrong type (e.g. a video option with no video streams) or that it is a private option of some encoder which was not actually used for any stream.
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (png (native) -> ffv1 (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Output #0, avi, to 'output.avi':
  Metadata:
    ISFT            : Lavf58.18.102
    Stream #0:0: Video: ffv1 (FFV1 / 0x31564646), bgr0, 5891x2160, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 60 fps, 60 tbn, 60 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.30.100 ffv1
frame=  600 fps=4.0 q=-0.0 Lsize=  100850kB time=00:00:10.00 bitrate=82616.4kbits/s speed=0.067x
video:100830kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.019776%`

Attached is a link to the file output https://cernbox.cern.ch/index.php/s/ggEtDZmwxqzap3Y

How do I turn a sequence of png images into a losslessly compressed video?

Thank you for any help

Comment: What specifically do you mean with "obviously lossy" in the case of the first command? That should produce what you want, except that many players cannot handle YUV 4:4:4 as pixel format. Make sure you are using a somewhat recent version of VLC. Is your requirement that the video should be playable on most devices / players? In this case you cannot go “fully lossless”, as the color will have to be subsampled to 4:2:0.

Comment: @slhck No, I have no requirements that it should be playable on any devices other than my own. By obviously lossy I mean I can see immediately the output is very compressed, the diffuse red circular spot in the first image comes out as a series of very visible thick concentric bands of colour.

Comment: @slhck I have edited the main post to include a screenshot of the obviously lossy video. (I thought perhaps this might have to do with upscaling but I tried without upscaling and the same concentric bands are visible)


I am fairly confident I should be using a recent version of VLC. I am not sure how you check what specific version you are on, but I only just downloaded it yesterday from here https://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-windows.html (specifically because windows media player wouldn't load it) and when I check for updates it tells me I have the latest version of VLC media player.

Comment: The problem you're experiencing (color banding) is due to converting from the RGB color space to YUV (strictly speaking YCbCr). Use a video codec that supports the RGB color space, e.g. `ffv1` (it's lossless, no need to set any parameters)

Comment: Hi @slhck , thanks very much. Sorry I know very little about video encoding, so just to doublecheck, do you mean change 


ffmpeg -framerate 60 -i %d.png -vf scale=-1:2160 -c:v libx264 -crf 0 -preset veryslow -c:a libmp3lame -b:a 320k output.mp4

to

ffmpeg -framerate 60 -i %d.png -vf scale=-1:2160 -c:v ffv1 -c:a libmp3lame -b:a 320k output.mp4 ?

Thanks again for the help

Comment: @Slhck I tried running ffmpeg -framerate 60 -i %d.png -vf scale=-1:2160 -c:v ffv1 -c:a libmp3lame -b:a 320k output.avi (with .mp4 ffmpeg would not run), and the video is just a blank black screen in both VLC and windows meida player.

Comment: Yes, that should work, and I could successfully play the resulting video in my case, with VLC. (Forget Windows Media Player for testing such things.) Could you add the full command line output from the last run, and perhaps the output video as a sample?

Comment: @slhck hi, I have added the cmd line output and a link to the output video to the bottom of the main post. I have attempted uninstalling and reinstalling VLC, however I still just see a black blank screen when I try to open the video. However, I have tested it with both 3 images and 600, and it lasts for the appropriate amount of time (less than 1 second with 3 images, 10 seconds with the 600). 

I have also tried with VLC freshly installed on a ubuntu machine and this also just shows a black blank screen.

Thanks again for all the help

Comment: Sorry for the late response. The video you've uploaded looks fine to me and does not show any banding. I can view it with the latest version of VLC (under macOS). Another codec worth trying is ProRes via `-c:v prores_ks` (there is `prores` as well but it does not support 4:4:4 encoding).

Comment: @slhck no problem, you've been a great help. Huh, weird. I guess VLC must just be better supported on macOS than windows and ubuntu. I've tried prores_ks that also just gives me a black screen on a fresh install of VLC, will just have to borrow someone's mac I suppose.

Thanks for the patience and help